# Using aggregate function on data masked column returns zeroes

Tags: sql-server, aggregate, data-masking

Recently we have implemented dynamic data masking in SQL Server 2019 database in order to hide sensitive information from developers. However, for testing purposes I'd like them to see close-to-real values, so my mask looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE fin.Salaries
(
    TargetMonth    DATE            NOT NULL,
    Login          VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
    Department     VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
    AmountUSD      MONEY           MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'random(500, 5000)') NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Salaries PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (TargetMonth, Login, Department)
)
```

It works fine for simple queries, however aggregate functions seem to always return zero values. I haven't found anything on this in the documentation, so the question is whether this is an intended behavior and is there any way to get non-zero values from aggregated data masked column?

```
SELECT   TargetMonth,
         AVG(AmountUSD) -- Returns all zeroes
FROM     fin.Salaries
GROUP BY TargetMonth
```

Comment: oyln database users with full access rights will se the data unmasked, the rests will onöy get masked , data and any aggregation function doesn't make sense on that

Comment: @nbk , I'm not expecting unmasked data here, just some random non-zero values like I get when running query without AVG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since dynamic data masking is performed right before returning the query result to the user, applying functions such as `AVG` will not have the masked data as a resultset.

You can see this in the execution plan, the masking function appears right before the select (in other words, returning the data to the user):

[image]

While the actual aggreggate happens in the compute scalar right behind the masking function:

[image]

With `[EXPR1008]` and `[EXPR1009]` being a count and a sum:

```
<ColumnReference Column="Expr1008" />
<ScalarOperator ScalarString="Count(*)">
<Aggregate AggType="countstar" Distinct="false" />
<ColumnReference Column="Expr1009" />
<ScalarOperator ScalarString="SUM([Test].[dbo].[Salaries].[AmountUSD])">
```

And, with the datamask function being applied after the aggregate functions, it is set to 0 as a result of the `DataMask([Expr1002],0x05000000,(1),(0),(0),(0))` function.

This does not mean that all `DataMask` function executions on aggreggates and the corresponding datatypes will return 0, only that in this case it does.